# How to fix a "i in range(n)" when it refuses to repeat

Tags: python

I am trying to copy the code from a Python tutorial https://youtu.be/BfS2H1y6tzQ?t=156 and copied it word for word, but it isn't working like in the video.

```
import random

def random_walk(n):
    """Return coodrinates after 'n' block random walk."""
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(n):
        step = random.choice(['N','S','E','W'])
        if step == 'N':
            y = y + 1
        elif step == 'S':
            y = y - 1
        elif step == 'E':
            x = x + 1
        elif step == 'W':
            x = x - 1
        return (x, y)
```

I expected the "for i in range(n):" to repeat the next line for the n amount of times, but it seems to only try it once, thus diving the new coordinates a one number difference.  I was expecting a result more like the one at https://youtu.be/BfS2H1y6tzQ?t=176. For reference, I'm using Python 3.7.3.

Comment: Your `return` is indented too far. You're returning after one iteration of your loop. Move the return out of the for loop ( i.e. indent to the same level as `for`).

Comment: No stinking way, I feel like an idiot; thanks, solved.

Comment: Don't feel bad, we see it all the time.

Comment: Thanks, man. Say, how do I tag this as solved?

Comment: Click the checkbox next to an answer to mark the question solved. If there are no good answers, you can add one yourself. (That said, in this case, you might just delete the question, since it turned out to be caused by an issue that isn't likely to apply to others; note that that's only possible as long as none of the answers are upvoted -- as soon as one gets a positive score, the question would require a vote or moderator intervention to delete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning (x,y) in the for loop. Just indent it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` statement has a wrong intent, and you have to delete some blanks before it. Below is the correct code, and be careful of the last line.

```py
import random

def random_walk(n):
    """Return coodrinates after 'n' block random walk."""
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(n):
        step = random.choice(['N','S','E','W'])
        if step == 'N':
            y = y + 1
        elif step == 'S':
            y = y - 1
        elif step == 'E':
            x = x + 1
        elif step == 'W':
            x = x - 1

    return (x, y)
```